# Read Emails from Office 365 via c# using refresh token

Tags: c#, outlook, oauth-2.0, office365, outlook-restapi

So I'm able to login to Outlook via OAuth2 and get it to provide my app with access and refresh tokens.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get Outlook OAuth2 to give me another token using the provided refresh token. I've messed with this code quite a few times trying to get something to work using C# HttpClient(). Additionally, I've tried to follow [this article](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet) and use the "native" "Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" library (what is this anyway?) to accomplish my task.

I could log in with this library and get an access code, but it wouldn't give me a refresh token. This particular library doesn't seem to provide access to refresh tokens, even if they are provided in the response.

Anyway, so here's the HttpClient code that I'm using to get an Access Token (this is from my callback Controller Method):

```
string authCode = Request.Params["code"];
var client = new HttpClient();
var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientID"];
var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
      {"client_id", clientId},
      {"client_secret", clientSecret},
      {"code",authCode },
      {"redirect_uri",  Url.Action("Authorize", "Manage", null, Request.Url.Scheme)},
      {"grant_type","authorization_code" }
   };
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",content);
var tokens = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MicrosoftOAuthAuthenticationModel>();
var originalRefreshToken = tokens.refresh_token;
var originalAccessToken = tokens.access_token;
```

originalAccessToken gets generated as expected. Now here's the part I can't figure out:

```
var parameters2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
      {"grant_type", "refresh_token"},
      {"refresh_token", originalRefreshToken},
      {"client_id", clientId},
      {"client_secret", clientSecret},
      {"resource","https://outlook.office365.com" }
   };
var content2 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters2);
var response2 = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", content2);
var tokens2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsAsync<MicrosoftOAuthAuthenticationModel>();
var newRefreshtoken = tokens2.refresh_token;
var newAccessToken = tokens2.access_token;
```

I get a 400 error from the server that says "Authentication failed: Refresh Token is malformed or invalid". This seems weird because I'm literally grabbing the refresh token from the response and using it.

Does anyone have any information that might help? Alternatively, does anyone know who to contact for help? Last, the goal here is to simply be able to persistently read emails from an inbox on office 365 via the API so I can get the email id, conversation id, subject, content, from email address, etc. and process it. Is there an easier way to be doing this? This can't be a difficult or uncommon thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the ADAL library (`Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`), you don't need to save the refresh token. The library saves the token and manages refreshing as needed for you. You just always retrieve the token using the `AcquireSilent...` (don't remember the exact method name), and it will pull from cache as it can and refresh when needed.

In your code your likely seeing this problem because in the refresh you're not posting to the v2 endpoint. Change your endpoint URL to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` and see if that doesn't fix it. If it still doesn't work, you might compare with http://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/.

Comment: Hi Jason! I have been using http://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/ as my main frame of reference, but just couldn't get the right combination of parameters and url to get refresh tokens to work. Additionally, reading these emails will be handled by an independent solution so I definitely need to store the refresh token myself. It seems like this would be a common... maybe it should be exposed by ADAL. Adding /v2.0 to my post URL did fix everything, however, the Request/Response window in oauthplay shows an incorrect URL for this call. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the playground. I'll make sure that gets fixed!